# Uses of SSH Subsytems

Tags: ssh

SFTP is probably the most widely used "ssh subsystem". [This O'Reilly chapter](http://www.hell.org.ua/Docs/oreilly/tcpip2/ssh/ch05_07.htm) gives some more usage examples; it presents subsytems as "shortcuts" to various commands that can be used.

How do you use this subsytem feature ?

Is there a practical way to limit an ssh key to a subsystem, possibly replacing command restriction option of ssh keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very cool feature that's based on SFTP is sshfs(1):

```
sshfs -o workaround=all user@remotehost:/ /path/to/localdir
```

will mount the whole disk at *remotehost* at the local directory /path/to/localdir . No installation necessary at remotehost,all you need is the sshfs program.

Comment: I concur.  SSHFS is amazing, but I don't think this answers the given question.

Comment: Hm, maybe not, but as I read the post, there were two questions. I replied to the "How do you use this subsystem feature?" part. :)